# Is the set of all projection matrices a convex set?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The set $\phi=\{P| P^2=P\}$ contains all projection matrix. Is this set $\phi$ convex?

Comment: Consider for any dimension the two simplest projection matrices, $I$ and $0$.  What about convex combinations of these two?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider 
$$
A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1/2 & 1/2  \\
1/2 & 1/2   \end{array} \right)\\
B=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0   \end{array} \right)\\
C = 1/2A + 1/2B
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In $\mathbb R^2$, consider projection onto the two basis vectors $P_1(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0),P_2(x_1,x_2)=(0,x_2)$, then $P_1/2+P_2/2=I/2$.